# Update window size and grid margin simultaneously

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom styled wpf window (borderless). Im having trouble with custom window animations, the problem boils down to when setting the window size and the margin of a grid (the parent to all controls on the window), they always update separately, either the grid will change its margin first then the window will change its size or vise versa (causing a very visible flicker). Is there any way to stop the window from drawing until the grid is finished updating fully? or otherwise force them to update simultaneously?

Here is the post animation code (everything up to this point is seamless), i don't think it will be very helpful though.

```
GridBackground.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.Width = NormalWindowSize.Width;
this.Height = NormalWindowSize.Height;
this.Top = NormalWindowSize.Top;
this.Left = NormalWindowSize.Left;
```

What this code does is transition between having a full screen transparent window with the 'fake' window on the GridBackground being offset via margins, to the window being the same size and position as the grid and the grid having no margins. As said earlier this code works fine, but the problem is that grid and window are not being updated at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, to change window size using dispatcher?

```
GridBackground.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
{
    this.Width = NormalWindowSize.Width;
    this.Height = NormalWindowSize.Height;
    this.Top = NormalWindowSize.Top;
    this.Left = NormalWindowSize.Left;
}), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

Comment: The flicker is still visible, i tried it with multiple priorities.

Comment: So maybe try to animate it using Storyboard ?

Comment: It is, the problem is transitioning from post-animation to a proper sized window

Comment: Have you any Winforms controls in window/grid? It can cause flickering

Comment: The animations works by (for normalizing) keeping the window at maximum size but changing the size and position of the background grid to give the impression that the window is getting smaller. Once this animation is done the window is set to the correct size and the margins (used to position the grid) are set to 0. However the window size and margins are not changed at the same time, resulting in the window apearing to flicker back to full size for a few milliseconds.